# Doxygen using Clang on C sources

Tags: c, clang, doxygen, doxywizard

Using Doxygen with `CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = YES` on a batch of plain C files yields many warnings that are C++ related, notably on assignment/initialization and type conversion.

On Doxygen, I also have `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C = YES`.

I can experience it with any trivial *conceptual error*, like these:

```
struct sTest {
    char * text;
    int value;
};

const struct sTest foo[] = {
    {"one", 1},
    {"two", 2},
    {"three", 3}
};
```

which don't generate any warning compiling for C, but in Doxygen log they results as:

```
Preprocessing C:/[path]/main.c...
error: C:/[path]/main.c:282:6: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings] [clang]
error: C:/[path]/main.c:283:6: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings] [clang]
error: C:/[path]/main.c:284:6: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings] [clang]
```

*Note: Yes, I know that the compiler/static analyzer messages are **grounded in this case**; however, I chose the example to clearly show that a C++ analysis seems to be running, not a C one as I would expect.*

That the same batch of files compiled with `clang -Wall -Wextra *.c -o out.exe` shows **no warnings**

[EDIT]

This is how I **hoped** to solve it:

> P.S.: What's important, for anyone facing it too, is that **I solved it** with `CLANG_OPTIONS = -std=c11` -- that's more or less what I expected **Doxygen** to do, when *optimizing for C*

Doesn't work on *Windows* though: when I add the option Clang fails to read all the input **.c** files:

```
Preprocessing C:/[path]/main.c...
error: clang: Failed to parse translation unit C:/[path]/main.c
```

**But** still opens all **.h** ones!

I mean that having in that path `main.c` and `main.h` only the second one is opened without any error. Yet have no idea why...